# Creating an Entity from a Query?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, entity

Is it possible to create an entity directly from query?

Not sure how it is. But I was told I can create an entity from query (Not VIEW).

My need is to join multiple tables and pull only some columns and use that as an entity in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by entity (an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would be helpful, IMO).

But, what you are looking for might be the [JPQL Constructor Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_select_clause).

> in the SELECT Clause A constructor may be used in the SELECT list to return one or more Java instances. The specified class is not required to be an entity or to be mapped to the database. The constructor name must be fully qualified.
>   If an entity class name is specified in the SELECT NEW clause, the resulting entity instances are in the new state.

Following is an example -

```
SELECT NEW com.company.PublisherInfo(pub.id, pub.revenue, mag.price)
    FROM Publisher pub JOIN pub.magazines mag WHERE mag.price > 5.00
```

You can use the above to invoke a constructor and pass it the selected values to instantiate your object.

Here is the link for an [example using HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select).